# How to exclude a widget from tab-ordering list?

Tags: qt, tab-ordering

[image]

(This picture is from Qt official site, and I take it as an example.)

**I'd like to escape some unimportant widgets from being tab-focused.**

(This strategy is useful if you have a widget that you want to quickly rotate between some commonly used `QLineEdit` to enter data and escape those rarely used settings.)

Take the picture as an example, is it possible to exclude **Width** and **Height** from tab-ordering list so I can use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to rotate only between `Name`, `Color depth`, `OK` and `Cancel`? I've searched the document and didn't find the option to remove widgets from tab-ordering list.

Comment: You can disable elements, if you don't want them to be focusable. Is it what you need?

Comment: I still want to use them. Thuga's answer is what I want: I can set those unimportant widgets to be `Qt::ClickFocus` and they will be excluded from my tab-ordering list, meanwhile I can still use them by click on them.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Change the [focus policy](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#focusPolicy-prop) of your widgets that you don't want in the tab order list.

*The policy is Qt::TabFocus if the widget accepts keyboard focus by tabbing.*

You will have to set it to `Qt::ClickFocus` or `Qt::NoFocus` to remove it from the tab order list.

See what different focus policies do [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#FocusPolicy-enum).

Comment: It works pretty well, very appreciate! Btw, setting `Qt::NoFocus` on a `QLineEdit` seems equivalent to disable it.

Comment: @Tay2510 Yes, widget with `Qt::NoFocus` set as its focus policy will not accept keyboard focus at all.