# How to capture Tab Key in Qt widget

Tags: qt, qt5, qwidget

I want to implement my own sequence for changing the focus of the active child widget using the Tab key. How to capture the Tab Key press event? I am using Qt5.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to change focus with <kbd>Tab</kbd> , you don't need to do those works, Qt has it as a feature.

**First:** set the desired widgets to be `Qt::TabFocus` or `Qt::StrongFocus` by `QWidget::setFocusPolicy( Qt::FocusPolicy policy )`

For example, if you want to rotate between 3 `QLineEdit` and 1 `QCombobox`, you have to assure that their focus policy have been set right. (Normally either `Qt::TabFocus` or `Qt::StrongFocus` will be set as default, but sometimes [you might want to escape some widgets from being tabbed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23953143/how-to-exclude-a-widget-from-tab-ordering-list))

**Second:** go to designer mode and click "**`Edit Tab Order`**" to enter the tab-order editing mode

[image]

**Third:** After seeing the numbers, click on them until you got the desired sequence order.

(Picture from Qt official site)

[image]

Comment: This is an accurate answer to my question. However there are some cases when editting tab order is not enough to do the trick. For example if the form is located in a tab widget and after tabbing to the last widget on a page to switch to the next tab page. I should be little more specific when asking :)

Comment: @UgaBuga Like I said in the post: **" sometimes you might want to escape some widgets from being tabbed. "** (check the link for more information) In your example, all you need is to set the TabWidget to be `Qt::ClickFocus` so you won't switch to the next tab page with Tab key. Besides, the focus policy can be set dynamically, so it's enough to do the tricks you want imo.

Answer (score 1):

Have a mouse press event or a event filter, get to the point where you have a `QKeyEvent`

Then only do something if tab was pressed

```
key_event->button() == Qt::Key_Tab
```

Comment: Above shows tab focus sorry didnt fully read the question description, this answers what the title says though, capturing a tab key event

Comment: title is "How to capture a tab key" though